# AutoML training error: Less than 50% of rows > successfully generated examples

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I am trying to build a classifier using GCP AutoML.
I've successfully created the dataset, but when training I get the following error:

```
 Training pipeline failed with error message: Less than 50% of rows
 successfully generated examples.
```

This is an imbalanced classification problem, so I am optimising for AUC PRC. Also, the data split is done using a date column.

---

Any ideas why I am getting this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I realise this is a very old question, but for me I think the problem was caused by the timestamp column (used for splitting the data) having more than one format (e.g. some looked like `2022-04-16 07:32:25.810000 UTC` and some like `2022-04-29 22:20:05 UTC`) in my source BigQuery table.

Truncating the timestamps to be consistent (like the below in BigQuery) fixed the issue.

```
SELECT
  ...
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, MINUTE) as timestamp
  ...
FROM ...
```